# How can I iterate an array of arrays and keep only values from a single index in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I am building a booking calendar using easepicker and importing data using a third-party API in a mySQL db. I got the data in the database and I can access it in Javascript (to which I'm new). I'm trying to remove all indexes but one from an array of arrays, but no matter how I try to do the loop I get a .pop() undefined, although I made sure the object is an array of arrays.

```js
$.ajax({
  url     : 'get_data.php', // this fetches the booking info from 3rd party => DB
  type    : 'GET',          // type of the HTTP request
  success : checkAvail,
});


function checkAvail(response) {
  results     = response;
  var results = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
  availables  = results.filter(a => a.isAvailable === '1');

  console.log(availables); // displays the array of arrays for avail dates


  availables.forEach((available) => {
    available.pop(2); // **Uncaught TypeError: available.pop is not a function
  });

  console.table(availables);
}
```

console.log(availables) output

```
[
    {
        "id": "79653836",
        "date": "2022-07-09",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "2188"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653838",
        "date": "2022-07-10",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653840",
        "date": "2022-07-11",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653842",
        "date": "2022-07-12",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    }
]
```

Comment: That's not an array of arrays, but an array of plain objects.

Comment: You have an array of objects, not an array of arrays. `[]` is an array, `{}` is an object.

Comment: If you want the dates, use `available.date`

Comment: What do you expect as result? It is not clear from your question...

Comment: Also, `pop()` doesn't take an argument. It always removes the last element of an array. I think you're confusing it with the similar Python function.

Comment: remove this line : `results  = response;`

Comment: `Array.pop()` doesn't accept argument -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop   (_and this is a method, not a function_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`availables` is an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

To get a particular property from an object, use `.propname`, so use `available.date` to get the date.

You can use `map()` to return a new array that uses this to get the properties.

```js
const availables = [
    {
        "id": "79653836",
        "date": "2022-07-09",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "2188"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653838",
        "date": "2022-07-10",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653840",
        "date": "2022-07-11",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    },
    {
        "id": "79653842",
        "date": "2022-07-12",
        "isAvailable": "1",
        "price": "1750"
    }
];

const dates = availables.map(a => a.date);
console.log(dates);
```